# Preview app keep crashing (13.2.1 (22D68))

Tags: macos, pdf, preview, crash

I edited a PDF with Acrobat, but now when I try to open Preview, it crashes immediately without generating a bug report (it did the first time).

I tried to locate the com.apple.Preview.plist file to delete it, but I can't find it. I have also rebooted my computer several times, but the issue persists. Do you have any suggestions for what I can do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does the PDF open in Acrobat correctly? Deleting the .plist is unlikely to be a fix. Also, if rebooting doesn't fix it, then there's no point doing that again. Can you post the PDF? Are other PDFs saved from Acrobat OK in Preview? Can you open the PDF in Safari? Quick Look preview?

Comment: This same issue is happening to me. Usually I just use Preview to combine PDFs, make quick edits, sign, etc. But now, when I even try to just open a PDF and try printing, it just crashes.
If I go to delete a page, same result. Sometimes, it will delete the page but won't let me "save" it and crashes when I hit cmd+s.
I also don't have Adobe Acrobat installed on this computer. Not sure what caused this and would love to find a solution.

Comment: @benwiggy unfortunately, I now have the issue with every kinds of documents, PNG or PDF, or even if I just open the preview app, it's just stop automatically with no error

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the saved state for the app can cause this. To test quickly, you will want to restart the Mac and start preview and not load any document.

It's located in the Applications folder - so open that first (shift command a in Finder)

If it crashes, then clear saved state by holding shift when you start the Preview app - again - don't open a document - just open the app.

If that crashes, too - now make a new user account in system settings - users and groups.

Log out of the current user and log in to the new user and repeat the "start the app" to see if it crashes.

Based on this triage and new data - you can decide to reinstall / remove plug in / look to clear the saved data or just focus on the one document that makes the app crash no matter which user account / settings are hanging around.

Comment: I was expecting this to be linked to the saved state too, preview app work just fine on other account. but when I come back on my primary, it's just close immediately with no error.I removed com.apple.finder.savedState but can't found preview.

Comment: there is a lot of crash report in the consul app https://textbin.net/fjd9jezr2w

Comment: @Kevin You should be able to clear the Saved State by opening while holding down Shift, I think. Otherwise it's in `~/Library/Containers/Preview/Data/Library/Saved Application State`. You could delete the whole Preview Container.

Comment: Thanks dozens of times over @benwiggy - I forgot how to clear saved state and was too busy to look it up. That deserves an edit and prominent first step in my answer.

Comment: @benwiggy totally forgot about that, thank you so much